Solve aligned problem
I want to write like this in latex but i've faced many errors

I put aligned inside itemize



Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Could you please paste your code instead of using a screenshot? This helps others to copy and paste your code, and see where your issue occurred.

As for your actual issue, for your first item, the aligned environment needs to be in math mode. To use an unnumbered multi-line equation, consider using \begin{align*} and \end{align*}. And for both your first and second item, it might help to move your text ("la crochet de lie...") outside of the aligned and right after \item. This makes the most sense logically, as the text isn't part of the equation, but precedes it.

Welcome. // Honestly, would you retype everything (incomplete) from a screenshot to let the compiler help you locating problems? Please post code next time. Thank you

The initial text should be outside aligned and there should be a math display, rather than \(...\).
If you're writing in French, then you should load babel.
As far as I know, “crochet” is masculine and “dérivation” is feminine. Also “Der” and “End” should be upright (the original is wrong in this respect).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\frenchsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Der}{Der}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\newcommand{\lie}[2]{[#1,#2]}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\Der(A)$ est un sousespace vectoriel de $\End(A)$:
\[\begin{aligned}
  \delta\lie{f}{g}
    &= abc \\
    &= xyz
\end{aligned}\]

\item Le crochet de Lie $\lie{\delta_1}{\delta_2}$ est également une dérivation:
\[\begin{aligned}
  \lie{\delta_1}{\delta_2}(fg)
    &= abc \\
    &= xyz
\end{aligned}\]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


